# Ubuntu 22.04: Restarting networking.service flushes IP address of an interface

Tags: linux, linux-networking, ubuntu-18.04, ubuntu-22.04, netplan

I have migrated my App from Ubuntu 18.04 to 22.04, part of my app will take care of assigning IP to a network interface when it's set to run.

Now, I encountered a situation where, when I restart the networking.service the IP assigned to the interface by my app goes away -- yes, I decided to use networking.service instead of network-manager/ netplan and other new things, for a reason.

This mentioned behavior is not seen in 18.04, I need some tips here to avoid networking.service clearing up IP. Thanks!

Comment: IMO this is better suited for [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com) or [unix.se], but either way it would be necessary to know how you configure the IP address for any debugging to take place.

Comment: I have raised couple of questions recently in [askubuntu] and not even received any response,let alone the answers, so thought of checking it here, sure I will post this in Unix and Linux too.. my app assign IP to an interface via rtnetlink APIs

Comment: Your existing question also lacks details, you should extend it with more information. Edits also move your question back to the top of the list, making it more visible.